# cycles shadow issue, one object in the scene is way darker than it should

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, shadows

In my scene, one of the objects get's darker than the others, in the picture, the arms of the model should be the same color than the legs, the same materials are applied. The problem only occurs in cycles, when I switch to eevie or lookdev mode all the objects are shaded correctly. I've searched for the origin of the issue and everything seems to be normal, here is what I already checked

- Normals are facing outwards
- no custom split normal data
- topology contains no Ngons, holes or non planar faces
- one height map is applied but doesn't seem to be causing the issue
- no sharp edges applied
- does not seem to be "materials" related because the issue persists even when no material is applied

I've searched on the internet for answers but nothing applies to my situation... does anyone know what could be the issue ?[image: Screen capture blender cycles]

Comment: Can we see that material? Hard to quess what it could be, if you already tried normal possible solutions, maybe something is wrong in render settings or it is because of subsurface that I can see you are using... is there a way to share your file?

Comment: l dont think materials are the issue, the shading is dark even when no materials are applied, I can add an image of the node setup but it's really basic. and I don't know how to share my file, this site does not seem to allow it

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: what happens if you join legs with arms?

Comment: oh that worked, thanks a lot, do you know what the problem was, I still don't get it

Comment: Just by looking at it it's hard to tell, maybe some normals issue or smoothing problem?

Comment: Ok thank you anyway, that fixed my issue !

Comment: Joining two objects fixing the issue suggests some object properties were causing the issue. Perhaps *Ray Visibility*.